# ¿Cómo puedo agregar separadores de mil a mis inputs?

Tags: javascript

Soy principiante en esto de la programación. Estuve investigando y encontré que se puede agregar un método new IntNumberFormat, pero no me sirvió, o bueno, no sé cómo utilizarlo.

Este es mi archivo js.

```
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{

    var btnCalcular = document.querySelector('.calcular');

    btnCalcular.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        var compra = document.querySelector('#compra').value;
        var descuento = document.querySelector('#descuento').value;
        var valor = document.querySelector('#valor');
        var porcentaje = (descuento / 100) * compra;
        new Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES').format(valor).value;
        valor.value = compra - porcentaje.toFixed(3);
    });
});
```

Este es mi archivo html.

```
<div class="main-container">

        <div class="content">
            <form action="#" class="form-input">
                <label for="title">Compra</label>
                <input type="text" name="cliente" id="cliente" placeholder="Cliente">
                <input type="text" name="compra" id="compra" placeholder="Compra">
                <label for="descuento">Descuento 1% al 30%</label>
                <input type="range" min="0" max="30" step="1" name="descuento" id="descuento">
                <input type="text" name="valor" id="valor" placeholder="Valor">
                <button class="calcular">Calcular</button>
            </form>

            <div class="mensaje"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas cerca, solo que el formato lo debes asignar a una variable para luego usarlo. No me funciono con es-ES,, si lo que quieres es separar miles con puntos y decimales con coma en alemania se usa asi, te dejo las modificaciones:

```
 addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{

var btnCalcular = document.querySelector('.calcular');

btnCalcular.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    var compra = document.querySelector('#compra').value;
    var descuento = document.querySelector('#descuento').value;
    var valor = document.querySelector('#valor');
    var porcentaje = (descuento / 100) * compra;

    //esta es la variable a la cual le asignamos el formateador
    let formato = Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE');
    //ahora usamos formato con su metodo format()
    valor.value = formato.format(compra - porcentaje.toFixed(3));
});
});
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me sirvió.